How to pause listener
I have this listener for supabase auth/login/account creation. I want to handle user settings based on if the user has logged in before. However as soon as the person clicks login and the sign in finishes the navigator tries to change the page. This results in the next page not having settings it's expecting from the getUserFromDb call.
  _authStateSubscription = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange.listen(
      (data) {
    if (_redirecting) return;
    final session = data.session;
    if (session != null) {
      _redirecting = true;
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => HomePage()),
      );
    }
  },
  onError: (error) {
    if (error is AuthException) {
      UIUtil.showSnackBar(context, error.message);
    } else {
      UIUtil.showSnackBar(context, 'Unexpected error occurred');
    }
  },
);

Here is my signIn method call
setState(() {
    _isLoading = true;
  });

  await UserServ.registerOrSignIn(
      _isRegistered, _phoneController.text, _passwordController.text);

  if (mounted) {
    print('generated user id ${supabase.auth.currentUser!.id}');

    if (!_isRegistered) {
      _insertUser();
    } else {
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> user =
          await UserServ.getUserFromDb(supabase.auth.currentUser!.id);
      print('user data retrieved from db: $user');
      _isHost = user[0]['is_host'];
      print('retrieved user data $user + is user host: $_isHost');
    }
  }

